# Angular convert JSON into KeyValue pair

Tags: json, angular

I'm trying to convert my JSON data into a `KeyValue` array so that I can assign it to the options of a `p-dropdown` component but for some reason I cannot call `JSON.parse()` on the data

**key-value.ts**

```
export interface KeyValue {
    text: string;
    value: string;
}
```

**domains.json**

```
{
  "Domains": [
    {"North America (NAM)": "NAM"}, 
    {"Europe (EUR)": "EUR"}, 
    {"Australia (AUS)": "AUS"}, 
    {"Latin America (LAAM)": "LAAM"}, 
    {"Asia (APA)": "APA"}
  ]
}
```

**domains.service.ts**

```
getDomains(): any {
  return this.getJSON().subscribe(data => {
    console.log("JSON data.Domains: " + JSON.stringify(data.Domains)); //See >> output
    let sids: KeyValue[] = JSON.parse(data.Domains); // See >> exception
    return data.Domains;
  });
}

getJSON(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get("assets/dd.json")
}
```

**>> output**

```
JSON data.Domains: [{"North America (NAM)":"NAM"},{"Europe (EUR)":"EUR"},{"Australia (AUS)":"AUS"},{"Latin America (LAAM)":"LAAM"},{"Asia (APA)":"APA"}]
```

**>> exception**

> core.js:1449 ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position
>   1
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next] (utilitynet.service.ts:25)
>       at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:243)
>       at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:190)
>       at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:131)
>       at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:95)
>       at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:85)
>       at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:95)
>       at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:90)
>       at FilterSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:95)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.Domains` is already a JS Object. So you don't need to call `JSON.parse` on it.

Just do

```
let sids: KeyValue[] = data.Domains;
```

Also, I'm assuming that `getDomains()` is a method that you're going to call from a component and subscribe to it in there only.

So just refactor your code like this:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

getDomains(): any {
  return this.getJSON().pipe(
    map(data => data.Domains)
  );
}

...

getJSON(): Observable < any > {
  return this.http.get("assets/dd.json")
}
```

You can then use it in your Component like this:

```
this.domainsservice.getDomains()
  .subscribe(domains => {
    console.log(domains);
    ...
  });
```

Comment: @AK47 Just updated the answer with how you'll use it to get the actual domain values in your Component.